# Install OS X replacing Windows on a Mac without losing data

Tags: macos, windows

My brother installed Windows 7 on my Mac. Now I am trying to install OS X Lion  but when I select Reinstall OS X, I am not able to select any drive. One of my drive has 1.27 TB of data. Is it possible to install OS X without losing data?

Comment: If he installed Windows via Boot Camp, you may be in luck. If he did it directly from a Windows installer USB/DVD without Boot Camp, then Windows will have destroyed the original Mac partitioning & possibly overwritten your old data. You need to edit your question & add this information, so we can go to the next step...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to reinstall OS X without formatting and losing data. If you want to keep your data, recover the data to another drive or to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

On windows create second partition formatted as ExFAT. Move data you need to second partition. Then run OS X Recovery Partition. Format first partition, install OS X. Then move data from second partition to first and delete second partition.

Comment: That's basically same answer as I stated.

Comment: I've just described it with more details.